# When use Safari‘s Develop->Show page source, what's the difference between Elements and Resources?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, safari

When using Safari's develop tool to obtain the webpage's source code, there seems two columns, one is Elements, another is Resources. For some webpages, they are different, while for others, they are the same. And there is only Elements in Chrome.

In Safari's Elements I can easily locate the elements I want, but in Resources I can't.

This surely matters cuz I want to scrape a webpage whose Elements and Resources are different...And when I code like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

params = {"TPL_username": "xxxx", "TPL_password": "1xxx"}
tb = requests.post("https://login.xxxx.com/",data=params)
r = requests.get('http://www.xxxx.com',cookies=tb.cookies)
content = r.content
print(content)
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser") 
timelists = bs.find_all("span", {"class": "bought-wrapper-mod__create-time___yNWVS"})
print(timelists)
```

the print output(`content`) is the Resources rather than the Elements which I want. So I can't locate the element with Resources, and it is obvious that the code I see in Resources is not the real source code of the webpage. So why is that? `requests.get` doesn't return the real source code of the webpage?

Comment: Imagine a webpage being built by javascript... What gets delivered from the server and what gets rendered by the browser could be very different.

Comment: So, how can I scrap the elements I want... do you have some tutorial to recommend?